# understanding row context transition to filter context

Tags: powerbi

just trying to understand context transition wrt below.
this does not have implicit calculate in the filter argument of calculate, only a table name.  Now assuming I have a country name in the BI visual from customer table, what sort of context transition will this trigger?

=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Sales),Customer)

will it be just row context transitioning to filter context ie All rows from customer table become columns due to filter context and filter propagation.

Is my understanding correct?

Thanks

trying to interpret the results